# How to determine if anything has been entered into the console window?

Tags: java

In Java, I'm looking for a method that would allow me to wait for the user to press any key before continuing (or if one does not currently exist, I'm looking to implement it with a BufferedReader, if possible). How would I determine if the user has typed *any key* - not just enter?

This would be somewhat similar to something like [Console.ReadKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx) in C#.

Comment: Have a look at - http://jline.sourceforge.net/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [jcurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/).

Sample:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String []args){
     jcurses.system.InputChar ch;
     ch=jcurses.system.Toolkit.readCharacter(); 
     System.out.println(ch.getCode());
  }
}
```

Comment: So, do you really think that the only/best option would be to use one o the external libraries? There's no way to just "write your own" (not in an attempt to reinvent the wheel, just to create a single method that gets the job done)?

Comment: I've used this lib in my work. (Console has nothing to do with java platform/programming - Its an OS terminal window)