# Java - key event listener

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Is it possible to bind an action listener for keyboard events? E.g., I would like to write a program which computes something in the background, and when a key is pressed on the keyboard, the program executes a callback (a block of code).

Needless to say that the program is a command line program without any fancy GUI.
Any short snippet will be great :)

Comment: *"Needless to say that the program is a command line program"* So read `System.in` & do whatever is appropriate on receiving new data.  *"Is it possible to bind an action listener for keyboard events?"* not in a command-line based app. ..and what millennium is this?  Add a GUI.

Comment: A console app? You could just read `System.in` and do whatever you want to do read character/string

Comment: gui is for weak people :) anyway, your approaches will force me to use a polling, i.e. iterate over the stream and see whether there is input on it, which spends cpu power and the method itself is blocking!

Comment: depict the following scenario -- the program is launched, checked for io redirect/pipeline, if nothing is supplied then the program continues. your approach will not allowed it.

Comment: Gui is for weak people ? So i believe right now you posted here not from stackoverflow.com but you run.a commandline app that implements stackoverflowAPI ? @MrRoth

Comment: if nothing is supplied, nextLine() returns null. You xould exit the program. A

Comment: Also there is no pride in having things the difficult way , i think makings things simple is a.far more complex challenge.

Comment: :) could you please provide a snippet which works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to enable non blocking IO from console application. This cannot be done with JDK only, but fortunately there are several 3rd party libraries that enable this functionality.

Take a look on the following discussions:
[What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

[How to determine if anything has been entered into the console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015187/how-to-determine-if-anything-has-been-entered-into-the-console-window)

[how can I detect arrow keys in java console not in GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545388/how-can-i-detect-arrow-keys-in-java-console-not-in-gui)

[Listening to system mouse clicks from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291161/listening-to-system-mouse-clicks-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to attach eventLinsteners to a console app,

Console app? You could just read `System.in` and do whatever you want to do read character/string

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputString = sc.nextLine(); // you could swith it with nextInt(), nextFloat() etc based on yoir need

If(inputString.equals("whatever")
{
//do whatever , look into Runtime.exec to execute programs
}
```

Comment: please see my comment to the original post